# Get Weekday name from index number in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table which stores 0-6 as weekday value, and I want to display weekday name. E.g. if value is `0`, it will display `Sunday`, if value is `1`, it will display `Monday`, likewise.
Is there any inbuilt MySQL function for getting day name from Index?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: you could just use a CASE statement in your query...CASE WHEN WEEKID = 0 THEN 'Sunday' END

Comment: just create a lookup table and join with that (in case there is no function for that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DAYNAME( date_value )` is available in MySql; however, this takes a date, not an int. So if you have the date available, you can just use `DAYNAME(CURDATE())`, `DAYNAME('2014-01-07')`, etc.

If all you have available is the int representing the weekday, then a CASE statement might be your best bet.

`CASE WHEN 0 THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
      .....
      ELSE ''
END`

Answer (score 13):

As @Aliminator mentioned, you could use [`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) with a `DATE`.

However, if you don't want to change your schema, here is a nifty hack for you:

```
 SELECT DAYNAME(CONCAT("1970-09-2", dayIndex)) FROM your_table;
```

This is based on the fact that 1970-09-20 was a Sunday, the 21st was a Monday, and so on.

Comment: Your'e a genius! Thank You!

Comment: The only issue with this is that MySQL DAYOFWEEK function starts with 1 instead of 0 for Sunday.  So, you're always going to be doing math of -1.  Since I'm writing this in 2018 I would suggest you use 2018-03-1x where 2018-03-11 is Sunday.  The entire statement would be:  SELECT DAYNAME(CONCAT('2018-03-1', dayIndex)) from your_table;

Answer (score 2):

### `Method 1:`

Use a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select *,
case when weekid = 0 then 'Sunday'
when weekid = 1 then 'Monday'
when weekid = 2 then 'Tuesday'
when weekid = 3 then 'Wednesday'
when weekid = 4 then 'Thursday'
when weekid = 5 then 'Friday'
when weekid = 6 then 'Saturday'
else null end as WeekName
from your_table;
```

### `Method 2:`

You can create a table for storing the week names and select it using `JOIN`.

**Table weekName**

```
create table tblWeekName
(
    id int,
    weekName varchar(20)
);

insert into tblWeekName values
(0,'Sunday'),(1,'Monday'),(2,'Tuesday'),
(3,'Wednesday'),(4,'Thursday'),(5,'Friday'),(6,'Saturday');
```

Then use the following query to select the weekname.

```
select t1.*,
t2.weekName 
from your_table t1
join tblWeekName t2
on t1.weekid = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a reduced variant of previous answers - you can write one time your name of column in CASE statement to reduce length of your code.

```
case tt.start_day_of_week 
when 0 then 'Sunday'
when 1 then 'Monday'
when 2 then 'Tuesday'
when 3 then 'Wednesday'
when 4 then 'Thursday'
when 5 then 'Friday'
when 6 then 'Saturday'
else null end
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the MySql 5.5 documentation and there is a function when selecting called DayName() that you may be able to use. The down side is that you will need to use a DateTime variable, not an int.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname

I suggest changing your schema to take a DateTime so you can use DayName() and other built-in functions.

Comment: Don't know why downwoted, which @mbinette shows below, less effort than case-switch. AND!!! The function takes care of the database settings. In my version the day-number is 1-7 and 7 is Saturday...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you really need to store the name of the weekday? If you need to get the week day for the stored date try `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` with `'%W'` or `'%w'` format parameter. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Recurs on "Sunday"?