# Get last "active" day from last week

Tags: mysql, weekday

In my tool users can set their workdays (example: monday to friyday).When they save their settings, it will stored in the mysql user table.

In the next week (this week) i will get their "last workday". In this case it will be the friday. How can i get the last workday from every user with mysql?

Currently i save the workdays in csv (2,3,4,5,6 - 2 = Monday...) but i can change that.

I tried some stuff with WEEKDAY(), but it doesnt work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Get rid of that CSV and please normalize your table.  Your life will be much easier.

Comment: The first version was with single columns for every day. I dont say, that the CSV way is the best, i can change that, no problem. But my problem doesnt solved, when i change my table. How can i determine the last workday?

Answer (score 1):

```
DAYNAME(CONCAT('1970-09-2', SUBSTRING_INDEX(workdays, ',', -1)))
```

**Explanation:**

This MySQL string function [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(workdays, ',', -1)
```

...will give you the number of the last workday listed. (What it does is find all the positions where there's a comma and returns everything after the last comma, e.g., `SUBSTRING_INDEX('1,2,3', ',', -1)` returns 3.)

And this trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908851/2743458), using [`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) and [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
DAYNAME(CONCAT('1970-09-2', dayIndex))
```

...gives you the day name. (Since `DAYNAME` requires a date, this technique picks a date in the past that is a Sunday and ends in 0, in this case `1970-09-20`, and replaces the last digit with the returned index to determine the corresponding day of week, e.g., 20 = Sunday, 21 = Monday, etc.)

Put them together:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(CONCAT('1970-09-2', SUBSTRING_INDEX(workdays, ',', -1))) AS lastday FROM ...
```

...and you get the corresponding name of the weekday returned in the `lastday` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Below sql query might give some help to you. Hope you are asking for this only. It will list the last working day (`friday`) for each user.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE user_id, workday_id IN 
(SELECT user_id, MAX(workday_id) FROM tablename GROUP BY user_id );
```

Comment: Hi FallAndLearn (Nice nick btw!). The idea is correct, but the workday can be thuesday to thursday. Then i cant use your query. The query must look like "give me the last workday from user x" The idea behind that is, that i get data on the first workday, from the last workday. (Let me show, what i've done last week)

Comment: And where are you storing the last working day data ?